# Diango model property to return list of objects of other model

Tags: django, django-models, django-serializer

I have 2 models like this:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Company'
```

And another model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    company = models.ForeignKey(to=Company, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Product'
```

Now, I need to make a property in Company model which could return a list of all Product Objects, like

```
@property
def products (self):
    products = []

    for i in Product.objects().filter(company=self.id):
        products.append(i)

    return products
```

When I mention products (property) in CompanySerializer fields, it give me an error that it cannot return a list of objects.

Can anyone solve my problem and tell me what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you want the list of results in your API, you should use model_to_dict function. Like,

```
@property
def products(self):
    from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

    res = []
    for i in Product.objects.filter(company=self.id):
        res.append(model_to_dict(i))

    return res
```

And, then you can include this 'products' property in your Company serializer class fields. Hope, this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Django adds properties to your models dynamically that return a queryset with all related objects. By default the property is named `<model name lowercase>_set`

```
company.product_set.all()
```

The name of this property can be changed by passing `related_name` to the `ForeignKey`

```
class Product(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(to=Company, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='products')

company.products.all()
```

Comment: how can I return this result in CompanySerializer. I tried but it doesn't show the field.

`class Company(models.Model):
     @property
      def products(self):
          p = Product.objects.get(pk=self.id)
          return p.product.all()`

**product** is the related field name of product field in Product model.